# Limit of $0/x$ as x goes to 0

Tags: limits

What is the limit of $0/x$ as x goes to $0$, without using L'Hopital's rule? Clearly it should be $0$, but I'm not sure how it is any different from something like the divergence of $1/r^2$ which yields a dirac delta.

Comment: $\dfrac{0}{x}$ is equal to $0$ for all $x\neq 0$. Hence $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{0}{x} = 0$.

Comment: There are a few answers here that give the obvious response, but I think more interesting is the fact that OP is somehow thinking that there should be a Dirac delta in this question.

Comment: @Mike you are right, didn't notice that the first time. Anonymous, just picture (or use a free online plotting tool) what the two functions you mentioned look like: $0/x$ is just the $x$-axis, minus the point $(0,0)$ where the function isn't defined, whereas $1/r^2$ curves up steeply as $r \to 0$.

Comment: @user139388 I think something along that lines would make a good addition to your answer :)

Comment: What is a Dirac delta? It is certainly not a number (or infinity), and so it can't be the result of taking a limit.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need L'Hopital's rule. Every term of the sequence $\frac{0}{x_n}$ is $0$ where $x_n \to 0$, so the limit  is $0$.

**More Detail**

You can picture the two functions you've mentioned:
$
  f(x)
= \frac{0}{x}
$
 is just the $x$-axis minus the point $(0,0)$ where the function is not defined, whereas
$$
  g(r)
= \frac{1}{r^2}
$$
is a function which escapes to $\infty$ quite rapidly as $r \to 0$. Picturing these two functions should help clarify why they have different limits at $0$ (I've included a picture).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac0x = 0$ for $x\neq 0$, the limit of $\frac0x$ as $x$ goes to $0$ is the same as the limit of $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x = \lim_{x\to 0 } 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You could prove it formally by applying the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem):

> Let *I* be an interval having the point *a* as a limit point.
>
> Let *g*, *f*, and *h* be functions defined on *I*, except possibly at *a*
> itself.
>
> Suppose that for every *x* in *I* not equal to *a*, we have
> $$g(x)\leq f(x)\leq h(x)$$ and also suppose that
>
> $$ \lim _{x\to a}g(x)=\lim _{x\to a}h(x)=L.$$ Then
> $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L.$$

Setting $a=0$, $f(x)=\frac0x$ and $L=0$, let's use this theorem to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac0x = 0$:

Let $I$ be an interval around $0$, e.g. $(−1,1)$. *I* is now an interval having the point *a* as a limit point. Furthermore, let $g(x)=h(x)=0$, which satisfies $g(x)\leq f(x)\leq h(x)=0$ for all *x* in *I* except *a* (since $f(x)=\frac0x=0$ for all x≠0). Since $ \lim _{x\to a}g(x)=\lim _{x\to a}h(x)=\lim _{x\to 0}0=0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac0x = 0$.  QED.